# Maven - Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: java, maven

New to java and Maven.

When trying to add dependancy to the package `pulsar-functions-local-runner` I am getting an error:

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (make-assembly) on project java-function: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly failed: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes`

Using maven `3.6.3`.

I am after 3 hours of searching the web, what am I missing?

This is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>java-function</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-function</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pulsar</groupId>
            <artifactId>pulsar-functions-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pulsar</groupId>
            <artifactId>pulsar-functions-local-runner</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>                
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>org.example.test.ExclamationFunction</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assembly</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i guess they made some change in the jar of 2.7.0 because changing to pulsar-functions-local-runner 2.6.0 solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove pulsar-client from maven, and add pulsar-common. pulsar-common has the pulsar-client-api. There is a serious conflict between pulsar-client and pulsar-common.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pulsar</groupId>
      <artifactId>pulsar-common</artifactId>
      <version>${pulsar.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pulsar</groupId>
      <artifactId>pulsar-functions-api</artifactId>
      <version>${pulsar.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pulsar</groupId>
      <artifactId>pulsar-functions-local-runner</artifactId>
      <version>${pulsar.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <groupId>org.apache.pulsar</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>pulsar-client</artifactId>-->
<!--      <version>${pulsar.version}</version>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->
```